# Filebeat suddenly timing out shortly after pushing first logs to Opensearch

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, filebeat, opensearch

I am running filebeat 7.10.2 on a linux box and pushing logs to AWS Opensearch via a systemctl service.  Recently the service started failing with the following error:

**'failed to publish events:....net/http: request canceled (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)'**

When I restart filebeat I am able to connect to Opensearch with no issues and filebeat starts pushing the first few hundred records again, but then the same error comes up and it stops.  Has anyone come across this error before after successfully connecting?

I tried adjusting all the filebeat.yml configs but it made no difference.

Note that this filebeat instance has been running successfully for many months without any issue and suddenly this started happening out of the blue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you enable `logging.level` to debug in the `filebeat.yml` and see what is happening.

```
logging.level: debug
logging.to_files: true
logging.files:
  path: /var/log/filebeat
  name: filebeat
  keepfiles: 7
  permissions: 0640
```

Reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-logging.html

Comment: Thanks Musab but I tried that and not getting any more detailed error message unfortunately

Comment: You're welcome, it does not make any sense. If the filebeat stopped there should be some reason and that reason should be in there. If you are not see anything in the logs, that means out side of the filebeat killing filebeat-service

Comment: Looks like we were able to solve this adding the following configs to the yml file:

compression_level: 4
slow_start: true

Appears that files had been backed up for some time following a cleanup job outage on the box, and although the job has resumed, the above configs were needed to kickstart filebeat again.  Hope this helps out someone experiencing a similar issue.